# 2000 Kawasaki Vulcan Vulcan 800 Throttle Cuts at High Speeds (85mph+)

Tags: motorcycle, fuel-system, carburetor, kawasaki

The bike starts fine but it coughs a lot when giving throttle in first gear.  Runs great 2nd - 5th but when pushing around 85 mph or more the acceleration quits.  The engine is still running but feels like it's just idling until I slow to about 60-70 then the acceleration kicks in again.  Sometimes I can drop it down to forth and that will work but sometimes it doesn't.

I've had the carb cleaned, drained the tank, replaced the float/needle set.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi.  Wondering if you resolved this issue, if you did, could you post it. If not, have you checked your battery and your charging system?

Comment: OP not responding any longer to questions.  Need more information to answer.  I'm voting to close.